# Apache Redirect does not work…

Tags: apache, drupal, mod-rewrite, redirect

Once in a while I have to fuddle around with mod_rewrite or rather Apache's redirect. Now I have a simple task, that drives me nuts, cause I can't get it working:

Everything that was under `/journal/(.*)` is now under `/blog/(.*)`.

This is what I have now:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/journal/([^/]+)$ /blog/$1
```

If it matters: this is a drupal installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Drupal has existing rewrite rules in `.htaccess`. If you put your rules at the top of the file, Drupal's rules may override them.
- I don't think you want the starting `/` in your rule.
- If you're expecting the rule to redirect folks who use the old `/blog/` URL, you're mistaken. If that's what you're trying to do, you'll need to perform a redirection, like this:

.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^journal/(.+)$ http://example.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

since your rewrite base is / I think you can leave out the / in front of journal. so try

RewriteRule ^journal/([^/]+)$ /blog/$1

Also if you have any other rules happening you can append [L] to the end of the statement to make sure no other rewrites happen.